# Will an Egg move still be passed on if it is overwritten by the daycare's levelling?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-sixth-generation

I'm trying to pass on the move [Wish](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Wish_(move)) to a line of Eevees, as well as get the right nature and IVs. The Smeargle I used to pass on the move only has 1 IV, and I'd like to swap in another Eevee (one of the children which has Wish) that has 3 IVs.

However unlike Smeargle, Eevee learns a lot of moves, so I'll only get 5 or so Eggs before that Eevee forgets Wish, due to the daycare's feature of erasing old moves in favour of new.

So my question is, do I need to take out that Eevee periodically to re-teach Wish? (At the cost of a heart scale) Or will its moveset stay the same until its withdrawn, therefore continuing to pass on Wish anyway?

Comment: The Daycare Center forgets moves for you?

Comment: @Coronus - Yes, the top move is removed and a new move is added when the Pokemon reaches a level where it learns a move

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK as long as you do not take out the Eevee from the day care, it will continue to pass on Wish to its children. So if you are just keeping it in there to make a lot of Eevees, it will serve its purpose.

If you really want to keep wish on it, then you can remove it periodically from the daycare and rearrange the moves it has learned, so that Wish ends up at the bottom. The moves will be learnt by deleting ones from the top and adding a move to the bottom of the move list. This will give you a chance to keep wish on the Eevee while it is leveling and learning moves in the daycare. (You have a window of 3 move learns before you rearrange or else you will lose Wish)

If by chance you end up losing Wish then you have to go to the move re-learner and pony up a Heart Scale.

PS: I bred Stealth Rock onto my Tyranitar(Larvitars) this way. So I know it works out better and takes very little effort on your part.

Comment: Isn't it also possible to put in a lvl 100 eevee? So it won't lvl up and the moves won't be forgotten?

Comment: According to the question, he has just hatched a eevee with Wish and wants to know how to keep it. Levelling a pokemon to high levels beyond which it does not learn a move is actually a pretty obvious but time-consuming solution to the problem.

Comment: Awesome, so I can just leave it in there and not worry about hatching eggs that won't have wish. Thanks

Comment: @Robotnik Yup, new moves learned during the daycare are applied as soon as you remove the Pokemon.

Comment: @Jerry - Thanks for mentioning that here. I missed that in my answer and it is the main mechanic upon which it works.

Comment: My female mawille had children and passed down Seismic Toss with Ditto. Except, Mahwile forgot seismic toss before it was put in the daycare. So, how do you know what egg move will be passed if forgotten egg moves can still be passed?

Comment: @Dedenneway Are you sure the Eggs were not created **before** removing Mawile from the daycare?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to re-teach Wish as passing down Egg Moves only takes the *current* moveset into account.

Comment: I realize it only takes the current move set into account, my question was more about when that current move set is set. If the eevee learns a move at level 8, does that wipe the old move straight away? Or is its current moveset only recalculated when you withdraw it?

Comment: It learns the new move straight away.

Comment: according to Jerry & Samyam the moves are only applied once you withdraw the Pokemon though - meaning I can leave it there and not worry about it.

Comment: Hmm... that hasn't been my experience. I'll do some more testing.

Comment: I believe it only updates the move list when you retrieve the Pokémon from the daycare centre.